# Does integration induce a Kan fibration between the mapping spaces of CDGAs and cochain complexes over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, rational-homotopy-theory

For two CDGAs $A$ and $B$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, the mapping space $\text{Map}_{CDGA}(A,B)$ is the simplicial set with $n$-simplices
$$
\Phi : A \to B \otimes \Omega^*(\Delta^n)
$$
and simplices maps induced by the inclusion and degeneracy maps on the standard simplices. Now forgetting the algebra structure of $A$ and $B$, we can also look at the mapping space in the category of cochain complexes $\text{Map}_{\mathsf{Ch}^*(\mathbb{Q})}(A,B)$ where the $n$-simplices are given by
$$
\Phi \colon A \to B \otimes C^*(\Delta^n).
$$

For each $n$, integration defines a cochain map
$$
\int : \Omega^*(\Delta^n) \to C^*(\Delta^n)
$$
into the simplicial cochains on the standard $n$-simplex. I'm fairly sure this commutes with the maps induced by inclusions and degeneracy maps, meaning we get a map of simplicial sets
$$
\int_* : \text{Map}_{CDGA}(A,B) \to \text{Map}_{\mathsf{Ch}^*(\mathbb{Q})}(A,B)
$$
where  a map $\Phi : A \to B \otimes \Omega^*(\Delta^n)$ is sent to the composition
$$
A \xrightarrow{\Phi} B \otimes \Omega^*(\Delta^n) \xrightarrow{1_B \otimes \int} B \otimes C^*(\Delta^n)
$$

My question is: **is the map $\int_*$ a Kan fibration?**

So far I've really just been focusing on the case of finding lifts of the form
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^1[2] @>{}>> \text{Map}_{CDGA}(A,B);\\
@VVV @VV{\int_*}V \\
\Delta[2] @>{}>> \text{Map}_{\mathsf{Ch}^*(\mathbb{Q}}(A,B);
\end{CD}
$$
From these kinds of examples, I think that at minimum $A$ needs to be a Sullivan algebra. My reasoning is that $\text{Map}_{\mathsf{Ch}^*(\mathbb{Q})}(A,B)$ is always a Kan complex, so every map from $\Lambda^1[2] \to \text{Map}_{\mathsf{Ch}^*(\mathbb{Q})}(A,B)$ can be extended irrespective of whether $A$ is a Sullivan algebra or not. So, in this case, we should be able to find examples where the extension exists in $\text{Map}_{\mathsf{Ch}^*(\mathbb{Q})}(A,B)$ but not in $\text{Map}_{CDGA}(A,B)$.

Another observation is that $\int_*$ is not surjective (even on the $0$-simplices), since not every cochain map is an algebra map. I'm not sure if this is a problem or not either.

Comment: It seems very unlikely. For the related question of whether the maps $\mathrm{Hom}_{CDGA}(A, B\otimes \Omega^{\bullet}(\Delta^n))\to \mathrm{Hom}_{Ch}(A, B\otimes \Omega^{\bullet}(\Delta^n))$ combine to give a Kan fibration, you'd want $\mathrm{Symm}(A) \to A$ to be a cofibration, which is almost impossible. As you say, for $\mathrm{Map}_{CDGA}(A,B)$ to be a Kan complex, you want $A$ to be cofibrant.